# Connecting to Teamspeak with Telnet and C#

Tags: c#, telnet, tcpclient

i want to connect to the local Teamspeak Interface by Telnet and C#. I currently have no Idea how to realize it. I am using a TcpClient but i can only send one Command and i get only one Answer, how can i send as much as i want?

Any Idea would be helpful!